# ReferenceError: window is not defined, consider using the "jsdom" test environment (jest V28)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, testing-library

I would like some assistance in resolving this error.

[image]

Am using Jest V28.0.0.

Here's how my package.json's test script & devDependencies look like

```js
    "scripts":{
       ...,
       "test": "jest --env=node --watchAll --coverage --verbose",
    },

   "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
        "babel-jest": "^28.0.0",
        "jest": "^28.0.0",
        "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.0.1",
        "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    }
}
```

I also have a jest.config.js file that looks like so

```js
module.exports = {
    roots: ['<rootDir>/tests/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(test).js'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        ...
    },
}
```

My actual test file looks like so

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, cleanup, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

//components
import MyComponent from '../../../../src/website/Components/MyComponent'

test('should have the Add recipients text label', () => {
    const addRecipientsLabel = screen.getByTestId('label-element')
    expect(true).toBe(true)
    render(<MyComponent />)
    expect(addRecipientsLabel).toHaveTextContent('Add Recipients')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `@jest-environment` at the top of the file. Above even the imports.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

Eg.:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import React from 'react'
      
//components
import MyComponent from '...'

test('should have the Add recipients text label', () => {
    // test
})
```

Answer (score 2):

(*OP already did this, but documenting for future visitors.*)

As of Jest 28.x, if you are using JSDOM test environment, the `jest-environment-jsdom` package now must be installed separately:

```
npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

OR

```
yarn add --dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

Migration guide:

https://jest-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#jsdom